# Zoom CSS3 <li> element over another

Tags: css, html-lists, css-transitions

Hello my problem is simple I have multiple li element with and image and a text inside but the problem is that when I apply this code for zoom it on hover:

```
.thumb > li a {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    border-image: none;
    border-color: #E5E6E9 #DFE0E4 #D0D1D5;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.thumb > li a:hover {
    border-color: #00C0FF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #00C0FF;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: medium none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

It cover the previous li element so some border will not display correctly so I'm wondering if is possible to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: That CSS can do a lot of things depending on the context, Federik. Please provide the minimum html markup in order to recreate your problem. Use the SO snippet tool, plunkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/urwz0Loj/1/ here this is an example is not this type of scaling but is for seeing the 2 image get overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `.thumb>li a:hover` (the background is for becoming opaque):

```
.thumb > li a:hover{
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/urwz0Loj/2/).